# Minimum time to reach from city 1 to city N

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, dijkstra

There are a lot of graph problems that require some modification of the BFS algorithm. I just come across this problem. I thought of this question with just an extension of the standard BFS algorithm.
The question states that:

We are given a country, having N cities and M bidirectional roads. Each city has a traffic light, showing only 2 colors i.e Green and Red. All the traffic lights switch their color from Green to Red or vice versa after every T seconds. We can cross a city only when the traffic light is green. Initially, all traffic light is green. In any city, if the traffic light is Red then we have to wait for its light to turn green. Time taken to travel any road is C. We have to find minimum time to reach City N from 1.

Note: graph doesn't contain a self-loop or multiple edges.

For example:

N=5,M=5,T=3,C=5

Edges are:

1 2,

1 3,

2 4,

1 4,

2 5.

Here minimum time to go from 1 to 5 is 11 through path 1 2 5.WE can reach city 2 in 5 secs. then wait for 1 second for the light to turn green and then 5 seconds to go to 5.

Can anyone share his approach toward this problem? whether it is a BFS problem or some other graph algorithm required too?
Better to unsderstand if psedoucode will be there along with algorithm?

Comment: @Chinez u have edited question formatting?

Comment: Yes, I made the keywords a bit better.

Comment: That will be out of target for now. Just wait until you get an answer to your question

Comment: @BinduKumari You added the pseudocode part after you had already received clear answers on approaches to this problem. Asking for "pseudocode in c++" from them after the fact sounds suspiciously like you want someone to write code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Because all the cities start with same initial state, switch lights with the same frequency, and all the roads have the same duration, the traffic lights delay all routes equally.

As all roads have the same duration, this means that BFS will be an efficient way to solve the problem.  The only adjustment to the standard algorithm is to adjust the time at each node to account for any delay due to the traffic lights.

(If the roads had different durations, or the lights switched irregularly, then a more advanced algorithm such as Dijkstra would be required.)

Comment: it will be better if u provide a pesudocode in c++ for ur approach

Comment: point is we have to find aggregate sum of all the dalay in the shortest path.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming all edge weights have an integer number of seconds.

Note that the period of a traffic light is *2T*. Take your original graph *G* and duplicate its nodes *2T* times: *G<sub>0</sub>,  G<sub>1</sub>, ...,  G<sub>2T - 1</sub>*. If there is an edge in the original graph *G* from node *a* to *b* with weight *w*, then add an edge with weight *w* from each node *a* in *G<sub>t</sub>* to *b* in *G<sub>(t + w) mod 2T</sub>* for each *t* where the light in *a* is green. Add an edge with weight 1 between each respective node  in *G<sub>t</sub>, G<sub>(t+1) mod 2T</sub>*, representing the possibility to wait at a city.

Finally, add one more copy of the nodes of *G* to your graph, *D*, that will be used for the destination nodes. Add an edge from each node in *G<sub>t</sub>* to its respective node in *D* with weight 0.

Then the shortest path between nodes *s* in *G<sub>0</sub>* and *t* in *D* follows exactly your problem.

Comment: it will be better if u provide a pesudocode in c++ for ur approach .

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int

vector<int> g[1001];
vector<pair<ll,vector<ll>>> pt;

void dfs(ll st,ll e,ll vis[],vector<ll> rs,ll w){
   rs.push_back(st);
   if(st == e){
       pt.push_back({w*(rs.size()-1),rs});
       return;
   }
   for(auto u : g[st]){
       if(vis[u] == 0){
          vis[st] = 1;
          dfs(u,e,vis,rs,w);
          vis[st] = 0;
       }
   }
}

int main()
{
    ll n,m,t,c,u,v;
    cin>>n>>m>>t>>c;
    while(m--){
        cin>>u>>v;
        g[u].push_back(v);
        g[v].push_back(u);
    }
    
    if(n == 1)
    cout<<0<<endl;
    else if(n == 2)
    cout<<t<<endl;
    else{
        vector<ll> rs;
        ll w = c;
        ll vis[n+1] = {0};
        dfs(1,n,vis,rs,w);
        if(pt.size() == 0)
        cout<<-1<<endl;
        else{
        sort(pt.begin(),pt.end());
        ll te = 0;
        ll nt = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<pt[0].second.size();i++){
            te += c + (nt-te);
            while(nt < te)
            nt += t;
        }
        cout<<te<<endl;
        }//else
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please don’t just post a large block of code. Be sure to add some explanation of what you’re doing so readers unfamiliar with the syntax can learn from what you’re doing, and so readers who _are_ comfortable with the syntax can et a quick sense of how your approach differs from other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This Question was asked in a coding round of a company that i attended, I could come up with a **BFS solution** with O(n) Time Complexity.

*(The coding round is over now. So here's my solution)-Edited*

My Solution (Python 3):

```
def getPresentTrafficColorAndWaitTime(curr_color,traffic,cost_travel):
    #color
    val = (cost_travel//traffic)%2
    if val == 1:
        curr_color = 0 if curr_color==1 else 1

    #waitTime
    waitTime = traffic - (cost_travel%traffic)

    return curr_color,waitTime


def bfs(adj,visited,curr,final,traffic,cost_travel):
    queue = []
    queue.append(1)
    visited[1] = 1
    dist = 0
    # Red: 1 , Green: 0
    curr_color = 0
    temp_cost_travel = cost_travel
    while queue:
        length = len(queue)
        for _ in range(length):
            curr = queue[0]
            queue.pop(0)
            for i in adj[curr]:
                if i == final:
                    return dist+cost_travel
                elif visited[i] == 0:
                    visited[i] = 1
                    queue.append(i)
        curr_color,waitTime = getPresentTrafficColorAndWaitTime(curr_color,traffic,temp_cost_travel)
        if curr_color == 1:
            add_dist = waitTime
            temp_cost_travel = cost_travel
            curr_color = 0
        else:
            add_dist = 0
            temp_cost_travel += cost_travel
        dist += cost_travel + add_dist
    return -1


# Taking Input and creating Adjacency-list using defaultdict
n,m,t,c = map(int,input().split())
adj_list = defaultdict(list)
for _ in range(m):
    u,v = map(int,input().split())
    adj_list[u] = adj_list.get(u,[]) + [v]
    adj_list[v] = adj_list.get(v,[]) + [u]

visited = [0]*(n+1)

answer = bfs(adj_list,visited,1,n,t,c)
print(answer)
```